# SQL JOIN issue to discard results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

User #1 is linked to Sector #1

Project #1 is linked to Sector #1 AND Sector #2
Project #2 is linked to Sector #2 AND Sector #3

I want to retrieve projects - with their sectors - where the projects don't share any sectors with user #1

I've tried:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id SEPARATOR "#") s_ids

FROM
    projects p

LEFT JOIN
    projects_x_sectors ps ON ps.id_project = p.id
LEFT JOIN
    sectors s ON s.id = ps.id_sector

WHERE
    s.id NOT IN (
        SELECT id_sector FROM users_x_sectors WHERE id_user = 1
    )

GROUP BY
    p.id
```

**Exepected result:**

```
fetched projects = [
    {
        id: 2,
        s_ids: 2#3
    }
]
```

**Actual result:**

```
fetched projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        s_ids: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        s_ids: 2#3
    }
]
```

MySQL tables:

**users**

```
id
1
```

**projects**

```
id
1
2
```

**sectors**

```
id
1
2
3
```

**users_x_sectors**

```
id    id_user    id_sector
1     1          1
```

**projects_x_sectors**

```
id    id_project    id_sector
1     1             1
2     1             2
3     2             2
4     2             3
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: i'm using MySQL

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: show us the db structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join tables together -- unless you care about projects with no sectors at all.

To eliminate entire rows, you want to do the filtering *after* the aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT ps.id_project,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id SEPARATOR "#") s_ids
FROM projects_x_sectors ps LEFT JOIN
     users_x_sectors us
     ON ps.id_sector = us.id_sector AND us.id_user = 1
GROUP BY ps.id_project
HAVING COUNT(us.id_sector) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause is checking that there are no matches.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :)